# Can I use .NET Reflector to modify & recompile the code quickly?

Tags: .net, reflector, .net-reflector

Is it possible to use [.NET Reflector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector) (or an other tool) to modify and recompile the code **quickly** (that is, without dumping the source and then use [Visual Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio) to recompile it)?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can probably use the [Reflexil](http://sourceforge.net/projects/reflexil/) add-in for Reflector to do that:

> Reflexil is an assembly editor and runs as a plug-in for Reflector. Using Mono.Cecil, Reflexil is able to manipulate IL code and save the modified assemblies to disk. Reflexil also supports 'on the fly' C# and VB.NET code injection.

Comment: +1. I've used Reflexil and it works great. Reflexil is the way to go!

Comment: sorry for my noob question, but how to add this plugin to relector ?
I mean red gate's .net reflector ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, Red Gate's .NET Reflector. Run it, then go to Menu->View->Add-Ins->[Add Button]. Browse for the plugin .dll and that's it.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible with .Net reflector along with reflexil. First download reflexiil and then open .net relector and load the reflexil into it using View->addins->select the reflexil file(all dlls) and then load. After that open the required dll file and go to tools->select reflectil, open the code and identify the required item, then edit..give to the assemblyy and select save as to save it to new file

Answer (score 2):

.NET Reflector cannot do this, but other tools can decompile .NET assemblies, for example [FileDisassembler](http://www.denisbauer.com/NETTools/FileDisassembler.aspx) (an add-in for .NET Reflector).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Telerik JustDecompile](https://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx), which is free (I have no affiliation with Telerik).
After you load the assembly you wish to decompile, from the toolbar, click on Tools-> Create Project and it will create a .sln and .csproj which will include all the source files. You can even generate VB.NET source files if you prefer.