# How can I recreate codebehind files from an ASP.NET project

Tags: asp.net, dll, code-behind

Unfortunately, recently the developer that used to work on my site decided to disappear, I have all the files to my site (including the DLLs in the bin folder) but none of the codebehind files. This is making it impossible for me to debug in VS.NET.

Is there a way to recreate codebehind files for a web project from the DLLs in the bin?

I can already view the code in the dlls using a refactoring tool but the tool doesnt let me generate the asp.cs files.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Can I use .NET Reflector to modify & recompile the code quickly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279882/can-i-use-net-reflector-to-modify-recompile-the-code-quickly)

You can use Reflexil to completely regenerate the VS project.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to decompile the DLLs in the bin folder using something like [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have decompiled the DLLs, using that same tool. But it does not recreate the files. I need to recreate the asp.cs files

Comment: @digital1 - There are add-ons for Reflector that can save the decompiled source to file.

Answer (score 0):

[.NET Reflector Pro from Redgat](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)e will let you debug (generates source on the fly).

You need a [decompiler](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=.net%20decompiler) to generate source.